# How to retrieve JSON object inside another JSON object?

Tags: java, json

Guyz I am beginner in android. My question is how to get json object which is inside object. For example As shown in my below JSON data which I got from google places api, how to get `open_now` object which is inside `opening_hours` ?

```
"opening_hours" : {
    "open_now" : true,
    "weekday_text" : []
}
```

Below is my java code:

```
        // Check for all possible status
                if(status.equals("OK")){
                    // Successfully got places details
                    if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
                        // loop through each place
                        for (Place p : nearPlaces.results) {




                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            double rate=p.rating;
                            boolean ostatus=p.open_now;
                             String rvalue = String.valueOf(rate);
                            //Log.d("Rating",rvalue );
                            double latitude = p.geometry.location.lat;
                            double longitude = p.geometry.location.lng;
                            Location selected_location=new Location("locationA");
                            selected_location.setLatitude(userlat);
                            selected_location.setLongitude(userlng);
                        Location near_locations=new Location("locationA");
                            near_locations.setLatitude(latitude);
                            near_locations.setLongitude(longitude);

                        double distance=selected_location.distanceTo(near_locations);
                        double dvalue=(Math.round(distance));
                         String dsvalue = String.valueOf(dvalue);

               //   Log.d("distance", dvalue);

                            // Place reference won't display in listview - it will be hidden
                            // Place reference is used to get "place full details"
                            map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, p.reference);

                            // Place name
                            map.put(KEY_NAME, p.name);

                            map.put(KEY_EXTRA,rvalue);
                             int price= p.price_level;
                             String pc = String.valueOf(price);
                             String plevel="Inexpensive";
                             if(pc.equals("0")){
                                plevel= "Inexpensive";
                              }
                              else if(pc.equals("1")){
                                plevel= "Inexpensive";

                              }
                              else if(pc.equals("2")){
                                plevel= "Moderate";
                              }

                              else if(pc.equals("3")){
                                plevel= "Expensive";
                              }
                              else if(pc.equals("4")){
                                plevel= "Very Expensive";
                              }


                            map.put(KEY_PLEVEL,plevel);
                            String add=p.vicinity;
                            map.put(KEY_ADD, add);


                            System.out.println("open status"+String.valueOf(ostatus));
                          //  Log.d("Status",ostatus);
                           String tstat;
                            if(ostatus==false){
                                tstat="Open";
                            }
                            else{

                                tstat="Open";
                            }
                            map.put(KEY_STAT, tstat);

                       //    Log.d("price level",price);

                        map.put(KEY_DISTANCE, dsvalue+" M");
                            placesListItems.add(map);



                        }
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far.

Comment: please read [ask] : what did you try so far ? we are not here to make your homework : you have to try by yourself and come here if you can't find the solution.

Comment: You might want to take a look at JSON Parsing library like GSON or Jackson2. GSON might be easier for you to implement. This will help you a lot.

Comment: This is not my homework. Its part of my project I had decoded entire JSON file and I got stucked for this type of Object only.The others object was array and simple JSON objects.But this is Json object within object and I didnt find any solution for this so far.Thats why I asked it.

Comment: **"how to get open_now object which is inside opening_hours ?"** : open_now is not an object - it is the key of a key/value pair. Also, this question has nothing specific to Android.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  And as others have said, "open_now" is a (Boolean) value, not an "object".  A JSON object is enclosed in `{}`.

Comment: You have apparently used some sort of JSON kit to produce a "POJO", but you don't understand what you're doing or how JSON works.  You're best advised to use a simpler JSON kit that produces something like JSONObjects and JSONValues until you "get" JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You should use JSONObject:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
try{
    JSONObject openingHours = json.getJSONObject("opening_hours");
    boolean openNow = openingHours.getBoolean("open_now");
}catch(JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can read more about JSONObject [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Answer (score 1):

you have an `Array` in your `JSONObject` not an `JSONObject`, your model should be like this :

```
Class Item {
   ArrayList<String> weekday_text;
   boolean open_now;
}
```

now try to parse this model.

```
...
// reader contains your json String that comes from server
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Item item = gson.fromJson(reader, Item.class);
// now use your item object
```

Comment: Really bad answer. First of all, JSONArray has the syntax [{}]. Second, how is your answer helping in ANY way?

Comment: his question is incorrect. he said that he want to retrieve JSONObject inside another JSONObject but in his JSON, there isn't any inner JSONObject. he just want to parse an array and a boolean inside a JSONObject.

Comment: Ok, so you modified your answer, now it is more clear. You could still give an example of how to solve it. You could use Gson with the answer you provided.

Comment: @Carnal : A JSON array doesn't have to have syntax [{}] - it simply meeds to be a comma-delimited list of JSON values bounded by []

Comment: @Squonk: So you can skip the brackets?

Comment: @Carnal : The following would be a valid JSON array of strings `["hello","world"]` and an array of ints `[1,2,3,4]` etc

Comment: @Squonk: Yes of course, I was talking about JSONObject in JSONArray. Maybe I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @Camal : Yes, an array of JSON objects would be `[{...},{...}]`

Comment: @Squonk: Yes, indeed!

Comment: But there is no array of objects in the above JSON sample, just an empty array.

Comment: @HotLicks : My response to Camal was in relation to the first comment to this answer.

Comment: Yes, I was just making it clear.  `[]` is perfectly legit syntax for an empty array.